# VS 2013 release DLL linking to debug version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dll, runtime

I have the following (example) code of which I require to compile a release version.

```
// library.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL( int value)
    {
        printf("Hello from DLL : data=%d\n", value);
    }
}
```

The code compiles and links with one problem that it refers to the debug version of the
runtime library no matter what I try.

Platform        Visual Studio 2013 update 5

Issues -        Links to MSVCR120d.dll as opposed to MSVCR120.dll

Configuration   Release - Win32 Dll

Manifest        Present

Compiler CLI

/GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "LIBRARY_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\library.pch"

```
    Note: /MD is correct i.e. no static, no debug, dll
```

Linker CLI

/OUT:"C:_progdbg\Call_DLL\Caller\Release\library.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:_progdbg\Call_DLL\Caller\Release\library.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:_progdbg\Call_DLL\Caller\Release\library.lib" /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:_progdbg\Call_DLL\Caller\Release\library.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release \library.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

[image]

Dependency Walker shows that library is dependent on MSVCR120d.dll

Could someone please tell me which setting is wrong.

Many Thanks

Comment: The project's "Output Directory" setting looks badly mangled.  It has a drive letter (C:) but no leading backslash.   The underscore suggests a typo.  Greatly increases the odds that you can't find the DLL back anymore and look at the wrong one.

Comment: I think that's just how the site interpreted my pasted data - paths are correct , and thanks for the comments

Comment: Checked it is correct as pasted but is displaying incorectly

Comment: Why do you define NDEBUG?

Comment: My understanding of the negative logic here is a standard compiler term (when there are no custom ' if _mydebug'  custom profiles. Am I wrong ?